# Rails - Give & Check size for user of schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, rails-postgresql

I have multi-tenant application with postgresql https://github.com/fauzieuy/sekolah.

How to give user size of schema?
Is it possible to check the actual size of the tenant through the Rails application? If so, can i get a detailed view such as how many size of schema?

example:

schema name : public

table : users1 (role : admin site, admin school), accounts, pages

schema name : subdomain1,

table : users2 (role : teacher, student), contacts, articles

shared storage : 300 MB

schema name : subdomain2,

table : users2 (role : teacher, student), contacts, articles

shared storage : 300 MB)

etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following query works for me:

```
select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_table_size(c.oid))::bigint), nspname 
  from pg_class c 
  join pg_namespace n on relnamespace = n.oid group by nspname;
```

Note that it separates pg_toast off.  I am not quite sure how to integrate toasted storage into the numbers.